# Let $f$ is a uniformly continuous function on $(0,1).$ Is it possible to approximate $f$ by polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous function on $(0,1)$. Then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\widetilde{f}$ on $[0,1]$. By "Weierstrass Approximation Theorem" the extended function $\widetilde{f}$ can be approximated by a sequence of polynomials. Then, obviously if we remove the endpoints $0$ and $1$, then $f$ can be approximated by a sequence of polynomials.

Is my argument correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is correct.